# What does 3 dot means( ... ) in matlab??

Tags: matlab

I am new in matlab. Can someone please tell me from below code what does that 3 dot ( ... ) means??

```
defaults = struct(...
'ThresholdDelta', 5*190/255, ...
'RegionAreaRange', [180 1000], ...
'MaxAreaVariation', 0.25,...
'ROI', [1 1 imgSize(2) imgSize(1)]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three dots mean line continuation.

So the syntax:

```
defaults = struct(...
'ThresholdDelta', 5*190/255);
```

is strictly equivalent to:

```
defaults = struct('ThresholdDelta', 5*190/255);
```

Matlab expressions normally end at the end of the line unless they are specifically continued with `...`. So the syntax:

```
defaults = struct(
'ThresholdDelta', 5*190/255);
```

produces an error (`Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.`).

For the record, there is however one exception to the above rule: within the array building operator `[]` a new line is accepted without the need for `...` and it is similar to a colon `;`. For instance:

```
>> a = [1 2     % Use shift+Enter in the command line to go start a new line 
3 4]

a =

     1     2
     3     4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: The last line reads ambiguously to me. You are saying that lines always continue within the array building operator, no `...` needed. But first time I read it, I thought it said that lines cannot be continued using `...` within the array building operator. My bad, but adding another phrase or two would make it truly unambiguous.

Comment: @Cecilia I have updated my answer to make it clearer.